# Multi-Module Gradle Build Issue - No resource found that matches the give name

Tags: java, android, build, gradle

I'm having a gradle build issue where I'm getting the error "No resource found that matches the give name ..." for a bunch of @string references in my layout files in the core module which is referencing string from the XML files in other modules.

Here's my basic layout structure (this is an old Eclipse project that I'm trying to convert to gradle in Android Studio).

Main Project Folder

-google-play-services_lib

-MainModule (this is the main module that references the other modules)

-LibraryModule

-ZXing

There's currently nothing in my build.gradle at the main project level and my main settings.gradle only includes the following items:

```
include ':LibraryModule'
include ':google-play-services_lib'
include ':MainModule'
include ':ZXing'
```

Here's the build.gradle for my main module that should run when the application is opened.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':LibraryModule')
    compile project(':ZXing')
    compile project(':google-play-services_lib')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

All of the "No resource found..." messages that I'm getting are in the MainModule and the strings they are referencing are in the LibraryModule.  Any ideas on what might be going wrong in this build here?

EDIT: Adding my LibraryModule gradle.build file per request.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':ZXing')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please make the title more concrete? "Multi-Module Gradle Build Issue" could mean anything.

Comment: I added the error that I'm receiving in the build, hopefully that helps clear up any confusion.  Any ideas on what the issue might be?

Comment: Any chance you could add your librarymodule gradle.build file?

Comment: I went ahead and added it to the original post.  Thanks!

Comment: 1. Use the android-library plugin for your librarymodule. 2. your library and main module both depend on ZXing, that is sorta messy, any way to consolidate that?

Comment: Hi there bestdayever!  I went ahead and removed the module reference for the google play services and added the gradle reference instead and was able to remove the ZXing reference from my MainModule (it was only used in the LibraryModule and was redundantly referenced in the MainModule.  Alas, I'm still receiving the same error messages after syncing my gradle build files.

Comment: Did you also switch your library module to use the android-library gradle plugin instead of android?

Comment: Ah, so sorry I misread your initial comment.  I have updated that and it seems that it has gotten me past that error, hurrah!  You sir are a genius.  I wish I could buy you a beer to say thank you.  P.S. How do I accept your comment as the answer?

Comment: I answered below, There should be an option to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your LibraryModule should use the android-library gradle plugin. You can't share res between 2 application modules.

> A module is a
> component of your app that you can build, test, or debug
> independently. Modules contain the source code and resources for your
> app. Android Studio/Gradle projects contain three kinds of modules:
>
> - Java library modules contain reusable code. The build system generates
>   a JAR package for Java library modules.
> - Android library modules
>   contain reusable Android-specific code and resources. The build system
>   generates an AAR (Android ARchive) package for library modules.
> - Android application modules contain application code and may depend on
>   library modules, although many Android apps consists of only one
>   application module. The build system generates an APK package for
>   application modules.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-build.html#projectModules

Should shed more light on this issue